Finding parameters by EntityToken with Autodesk Fusion API?
I am having a hard time finding parameters using the Design.findEntityByToken method. I simplified my code to preform the bare minimum but am still having problems getting anything to return.
Here is a copy of my simplified code. I find a user parameter by name and I am able to edit it as expected. I then get it`s entity token and try to find that parameter by its token instead.
import adsk.core, adsk.fusion, adsk.cam, traceback

def run(context):
    ui = None
    try:
        app = adsk.core.Application.get()
        ui  = app.userInterface
        
        design = adsk.fusion.Design.cast(app.activeProduct)
        if not design:
            ui.messageBox('No active Fusion design', 'No Design')
            return
        
        design_parameters = design.userParameters
        
        #get parameter by name
        param_n = design_parameters.itemByName('length')

        #get token from param
        token = param_n.entityToken
        ui.messageBox(f'Token: {token}')

        #find entity from token
        entity = design.findEntityByToken(token) #entity always comes back as empty
    
        #entity is known to be a user parameter -> cast to userParamter
        param = adsk.fusion.UserParameter.cast(entity)

        # Update the user parameter's expression
        param.expression = '5.0'  # Set the new value here as a string
    
    except:
        if ui:
            ui.messageBox('Failed:\n{}'.format(traceback.format_exc()))


Any advice for getting this working? When I try to display 'entity' it comes back as empty.

You're making one assumption that is incorrect. The return value of findEntityByToken is an array, not a single item. Typically, the array contains a single item, but findEntityByToken always returns an array. This is to handle cases like where a token is gotten from a face, and then a feature splits the face. In this case, more than one face will be returned.
If you modify your code to get the first element of the array it works.
param = adsk.fusion.UserParameter.cast(entity[0])

